# Hide current image and show next one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to go through a div full of images and every 5 seconds, I want to hide the current one, and then show the next one.

Here's my html (with a hint of embedded ruby), check below for what it becomes on the client side:

```
<div class="home-images">
  <%= image_tag "taylor.jpg", class: "home-image" %> <!-- Rails way to create img tag with class -->
  <%= image_tag "wide.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
  <%= image_tag "sad.jpg", class: "home-image hide" %>
</div>
```

Here's my html (with a hint of sarcastic sadness):

```
<div class="home-images">
  <img alt="Taylor" class="home-image" src="/assets/taylor.jpg">
  <img alt="Wide" class="home-image hide" src="/assets/wide.jpg">
  <img alt="Sad" class="home-image hide" src="/assets/sad.jpg">
</div>
```

Here's my javascript (that currently doesn't work):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imagesLength = $(".home-image").length
  if(imagesLength) {
    $(".home-image").each(function(index) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
          $(this).toggleClass("hide");
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("hide");
          }, 5000);
        }, imagesLength*5000);
      }, index*5000);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: That's not really HTML

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G8hLn/1/

Comment: @Pointy that is HTML if you didn't notice the `div` tag. It has a little ruby embedded in it. Hope it doesn't scare you too much

Comment: @undefined yeah... went a little overboard after I couldn't get it a few times, just posted my last iteration of work

Comment: It helps a lot when diagnosing client-side problems to post client-side code.

Comment: Any comments on why the down votes? and @Pointy thanks for your help. I'll be sure to edit and think about it in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just do it with one interval

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var $ct = $('.home-images');
    setInterval(function () {
        $ct.find('img').first().addClass('hide').appendTo($ct);
        $ct.find('img').first().removeClass('hide')
    }, 1000)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G8hLn/)

Comment: A very elegant solution. Thanks very much. I added the if statement from my question because my JS is included on every page (rails stuff so not entirely relevant)

Answer (score 0):

you should probably set interval only once, on a function that will swap the images.
you would want to have 2 classes, .Visible and .Hidden,

in that swapping function n interval you would
go through all the children (images) with a for loop till children().length, and locate which one currently is visible.

then turn it invisible and set visible the next one i+1,

if the visible one is the last one, then turn i=0 to visible.

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like

```
var current=0;
setInterval(function(){
  $(".home-image").addClass("hide");
  $(".home-image").hide();
  $(".home-image").eq(current).removeClass("hide").show();
   current=(current % $(".home-image").length )+1;
 },1000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JCVnY/44/)